# How can we implement "Host Card Emulation (HCE)" with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, tags, nfc, reader, hce

We are working to implement HCE in flutter but till now can only read tag's information from the iOS version using the following codes -

```
void _readTag() {
  NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
    print("_tagRead:${tag.data}");
    result.value = tag.data;
    NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
  });
}
```

Ref: https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, Apple wasn't supporting HCE yet (and it was 1 year ago or so).
If you need to implement it on Android only, you can [use the nfc_emulator library](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_emulator)

Comment: OK, thanks. I will check and update you.

Comment: This is NFC tag specific and all the tags are not supported in android but work.

Comment: it's 2022 now, I want to make an NFC payment App, for android I know it's possible but for iOS, how can I emulate a card?

Comment: https://ijunkie.com/apple-nfc-android-less-secure-iphones/

Answer (score 0):

did you reach anything in making payment app by NFC ?

Comment: Try asking questions and doubts in comments.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32917756)